# SDK setting for Android release

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am using `cocos2d-x` for my game. Now I want to release it. In my `gradle.property` file, I have:

```
PROP_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=26
PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION=14
PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=26
PROP_APP_PLATFORM=10
PROP_APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a:x86
```

And I have the following dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
```

As you can see, I use the latest firebase admob ads.

1. what is `PROP_APP_PLATFORM`? What's the best number for it? (default is `10`)
2. Is my `PROP_APP_ABI` good? Does it cover most hardware? I removed `armeabi` because it's not supported by `NDK r26`. I am not concerned about APK size and want to cover most devices.
3. Are my 3 SDK versions good? I know what the 3 SDK mean (`compile` is the actual SDK to compile the code; `min` is the minimum SDK support; `target` is preferred to be the same as `compile`). However, Admob website says it only support Android 4.0+ (`SDK 14`). If in the future Admob decides to raise it to, say `SDK 15`, is my app gonna crash?